# How to web scrape multiple pages with different cities in unchanging URL - Python 3

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am accessing different websites to practice web scraping and trying to web scrape the following website - http://www.pizzahut.com.cn/StoreList

I have posted a similar question previously on web scraping the same website. The answer provided worked perfectly well allowing me to extract all lat and long for all stores in one city. However, I also want to extract lat and long for stores from multiple cities and encountered a problem which I needed some guidance. Changing cities do not alter URL as well.

The website is all in Chinese so I had to use google translation to make it into english and work along the way.

[image]

How I chose different city is shown in the image highlighted as red above. I basically clicked that link and chose the city I want to display. I would like to see stores' latitude and longitude for different cities or just Beijing given the example.

Below is the code that I have been working currently. The code below only extracts out latitude and longitude for all stores in Shanghai, which is shown on a default page.

```
import os
import requests
import csv
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

csv_name = 'Lat_long_practice.csv'
csv = open(csv_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig')

columnTitleRow = "Name, Latitude, Longitude\n"
csv.write(columnTitleRow)

for page_no in range(1, 14):
    data = {'pageIndex': page_no, 'pageSize': 10, 'keyword': '输入餐厅地址或餐厅名称'}

    page = requests.post('http://www.pizzahut.com.cn/StoreList/Index', data=data)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    print('PAGE', page_no)
    for row in soup.find_all('div',class_='re_RNew'):
        name = row.find('p',class_='re_NameNew').string #Get the name of the store
        info = row.find('input').get('value')
        location = info.split('|')

        #print(location)
        row = ''

        if location[0] == '':
            print(name)
            row = name + ',' + '' + ',' + '' + '\n'
            csv.write(row)
        else:
          location_data = location[0].split(',')
            latitude = location_data[0]
            longitude = location_data[1]
            print(name, latitude, longitude)
            row = name + ',' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '\n'
            csv.write(row)
```

Thanks for reading a long question. It will be really awesome if anyone could figure out how I can use python and beautifulsoup to extract all coordinates for different cities with unchanging URL.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your actual question?

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. Basically what I need is to go through different cities and extract stores' latitude and longitude. However, the default page  shows stores for Shanghai only. So, I was hoping to get latitude and longitude for stores in different cities. I will also edit my question to make it clearer

Comment: Then I'm sorry, man, but this question doesn't belong here. It's just a matter of translating the Chinese. After using [this](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pizzahut.com.cn%2FStoreList) tool, I figured there's a "switch cities" button. I believe this is what you were looking for

Comment: Yeah I know there is a button called "switch cities" which I posted above. It is also not a matter of translating the Chinese. What I want is how I can utilize that button in python and beautifulsoup to get lat and long for different cities not just from the default page which shows stores only in Shanghai

Comment: So your question isn't abut changing cities, but about exporting the coordinates?

Comment: Exporting coordinates for all stores in different cities. Currently based on the code provided, what my output is coordinates for all stores in Shanghai. However, I would like to extract coordinates for different cities as well.

Comment: That site seems to be using cookies to select the city, you will need to send more POST requests specifying the cookie parameter

Comment: @hir12111 Hey thanks so much for the comment. Would you be able to provide an example below under answers section to see how I can include cookies in the parameter for this site? Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click a city, the function addCookie is called, this is storing the city in a cookie following the format `iplocation={city}|0|0`
so you could get a certain city by sending the appropriate cookie, e.g:

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
page = requests.post('http://www.pizzahut.com.cn/StoreList/Index', data=data, cookies={'iplocation': quote_plus('北京市|0|0')})
```

Comment: Hey what does '1' in cookies represent? Is that the actually cookie that I have to insert?

Answer (score 1):

In https://www.tripadvisor.com/ also has static url.

You can handle this problem with `selenium` and `phantomjs`

```
from selenium import webdriver
url1 = "https://www.tripadvisor.com.tr/Restaurants-g293974-Istanbul.html"

executable_path1 = './phantomjs'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=executable_path1)
driver.get(url1)

#selecting links in the page
#doing another things

nextpage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS']/div[3]/div//a[contains(.,'Sonraki')]")
nextpage.click()
```

In Istanbul, there are 386 pages for related with resturants and all of the pages url's are same with each other (aka . unchanging url, static url)

It's one of my code to scrape tripadvisor. I hope it could help you

For more information , check http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the actual issue here is to maintain and iterate over all the available cities, one at a time.

1. Click the "change cities" button (xpath: `//a[contains(@class,'chose_city')]`).
2. Luckily the list is loaded all at once, so we have instant access to all the cities, without scrolling.
    All the cities are within the second `//div[contains(@class,'city_window')]`, so we need to iterate over its children DIVs.
3. We'll maintain our index, using the letter index (among A-Z) and the city index within the letter. So let's define `letterIndex` and `cityIndex`.
4. Because there are two `city_sel_box` DIVs, we'll just make things more simple, noticing the first internal `DIV` that's relevant is the 30th, with ID `chose_a2`.
   Hence, we can set `letterIndex = 31` and start from `cityIndex = 1`.
5. **First loop**: iterate over `(//div[contains(@class,'city_window')]/div)[letterIndex]`, with `letterIndex` from 31 to 52.
6. **Internal loop**: iterate over `(//div[contains(@class,'city_window')]/div)[letterIndex]/div/a[cityIndex]`, with `cityIndex` from 1 to the length of array `(//div[contains(@class,'city_window')]/div)[31]/div/a`.
7. For each iteration, run your original algorithm.

Let me know how it works and more important - if you have further questions.

Comment: I will definitely try this way. Appreciate your help!